# Phenominal Lavender is dying, really need help

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, herbs, lavender

I am not really sure what is happening with my Phenomenal Lavender. Bought this from Home Depot and I was told it was a transplant shock but a month later, it is getting worse. Leaves are turning grey/brown on the inside center. I planted it in a 7.5" Terra cotta planter. I planted my other Phenomenal lavender in the ground but they didn't thrive either due to the heavy rainfall (according to google)so when I bought this, I put it in a clay planter. As far as I know I have done everything by the book.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |